# Nested child in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this.

```
var main_childs = [
    {child_name: 1, childs:[2,4]},
    {child_name: 2, childs:[3]},
    {child_name: 3, childs:""},
    {child_name: 4, childs:""}
]
```

main_child.childname 1 have childs 2 and 4 that exist in main_childs so if main_childs.child_name is a child of one of the child name it will output like this

```
final_childs = [
    {
        1: {
            name: 1,
            childs: [
                {
                    name: 2, 
                    childs: [
                            {
                                name: 3, 
                                childs: []
                            },

                        ],
                    name: 4,
                    childs:[]

                }
            ]
        },

    }
]
```

I'm trying to solve it using this function

```
  function recursive(main_childs){
   main_childs.forEach(i=> {
       if(i.childs.length>0){
         recursive(i.childs)
       }
  })
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You've forgot to show us your attempts (even pseudo code) to solve your issue yourself

Comment: You are trying to build [a tree data structure](https://adrianmejia.com/data-structures-for-beginners-trees-binary-search-tree-tutorial/) - is child 1 guaranteed to be the root node of the tree?

Comment: yes sir @Taxel  I'm trying to solve it using recursive function but I can't  solve it

Comment: I believe recursion will make this problem a lot harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @Ouroborus Can u recommend me any solution to solve this sir ?

Comment: Looking at the function that you currently have I would like to point out a couple of things. Make sure that you actually return something.
You probably want to have a look at the "map" function.
The final function will probably consist of four parts.
   1. Find all the children of the current child
   2. Filter out the once that doesn't exist
   3. Build the subtrees for those children
   4. Construct and return an object containing the subtrees of the children

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: I have add a function that search all parents

Try this:

```js
var main_childs = [
    {child_name: 1, childs:[2,4]},
    {child_name: 2, childs:[3]},
    {child_name: 3, childs:""},
    {child_name: 4, childs:""},
    {child_name: 5, childs:[]}
]

var final_childs=[]

var parents=getParents();

parents.forEach(child=>{
    var parent={name:child.child_name,childs:[]};
  recursiveFunc(parent,child.childs);
  final_childs.push({});
  final_childs[final_childs.length-1][parent.name]=parent;
}

)
console.log(final_childs);

function recursiveFunc(parent,childNames){
  if(childNames=="")
    return
  childNames.forEach(childName=>{
    var child={name:childName,childs:[]}
    var main_child=main_childs.find(el=>el.child_name==childName);
    recursiveFunc(child,main_child.childs)
    parent.childs.push(child)
  })
}


function getParents(){
  let childs=[];
  let parents=[];
  main_childs.forEach(child=>childs.push(child.childs));
  childs=childs.flat(2);
  main_childs.forEach(child=>{
    let name=childs.find(el=>child.child_name==el);
    if(name==null){
      parents.push(child);
    }
  });
  return parents; 
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but when I added new object {child_name: 5, childs:[]}  then the final_child must have 2 entries

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1 is not always root but other elements can also be root
and elements can be out of order as well
added extra element

{
child_name: 5,
childs: [2]
}

Wrote it hastily so ignore function naming, output looks weird but if you tidy it with tabs its the same
below code  does not handle cyclic dependencies

```
   var main_childs = [{
    child_name: 1,
    childs: [2, 4]
  },
  {
    child_name: 2,
    childs: [3]
  },
  {
    child_name: 3,
    childs: ""
  },
  {
    child_name: 4,
    childs: ""
  },
  {
    child_name: 5,
    childs: [2]
  }
]

//get all roots

const getRoots = () => {

  let allChilds = main_childs.map(x => {
    if (!x.childs) {
      x.childs = []
    }
    return [...x.childs]
  }).flat()

  let allRoots = main_childs.filter(x => !allChilds.find(y => x.child_name == y)


  )

  return allRoots


}

//recursive call
const transform = (obj) => {
  let result = {}
  result.name = obj.child_name
  result.childs = []
  if (obj.childs) {
    obj.childs.forEach(x => {
      let n = main_childs.find(y => y.child_name == x)
      if (n) {
        result.childs.push(transform(n))
      }
    })

  }
  return result
}
//creation of new structure
const createNewStructure = () => {
  let roots = getRoots()
  let result = []

  roots.forEach(x => {
    let n = {}
    n[x.child_name] = transform(x)
    result.push(n)
  })

  return result
}


console.log(createNewStructure())


//output
/* [{
  1: {
    childs: [{
  childs: [{
  childs: [],
  name: 3
}],
  name: 2
}, {
  childs: [],
  name: 4
}],
    name: 1
  }
}, {
  5: {
    childs: [{
  childs: [{
  childs: [],
  name: 3
}],
  name: 2
}],
    name: 5
  }
}] */
```